# nuxt anonymous middleware, how to set data on component

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

Does anyone know how to set data on a component in nuxt from within an anonymous middleware? For example:

```
 data() {
    return {
      title: null
    };
  },
  middleware(context) {
    context.???.title="fred";
  }
```

I'm running this within a Nuxt Universal App and it needs to be done server side rather than client side. Is this even possible?

Thanks,
David

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using the asyncData function rather than Nuxt middleware:

```
asyncData(context) {
  // Do stuff with the context
  return {
    title: "My Title created from context"
  }
}
```

asyncData runs before loading the page component and will be called server side on the first request. This is what I was looking for, as I needed access to the context object while needing to set component variables before loading the component in the client.